# grails where to store image dimension data

Tags: grails

I have a photo service that needs to be refactored.  Here are the current methods:

```
def getPhotoUrl(String publicId, String format) {
    getCloudinary().url().format(format).transformation(new Transformation().width(288).height(194).crop("fill")).generate(publicId)
}

def getGalleryThumbnailUrl(String publicId) {
    getCloudinary().url().format('jpg').transformation(new Transformation().width(205).height(205).crop("fill")).generate(publicId)
}

def getGalleryPhotoUrl(String publicId) {
    getCloudinary().url().format('jpg').transformation(new Transformation().width(950).height(950).crop("fill")).generate(publicId)
}
```

The photo service methods are all called from a taglib.

The methods are quite similar except for the image dimensions, and I have to add a few more methods with different dimensions.  While I can refactor to have one method that takes in the image dimensions, where would you define/pass in those dimensions?

-Put the dimensions in a tag lib hard-coded, and pass them into the service call.
-Put the dimensions in Config.groovy, and have the
   service load them from the config
-put the dimensions in
   Config.groovy, and have the taglib load/pass them to the service
   -just keep them hard coded in the service.

The dimensions will rarely change.

EDIT:::  Revised code

```
public enum PhotoSize {

    GALLERY(grailsApplication.config.img.gallery.full.height, grailsApplication.config.img.gallery.full.width),

    //def config = Holders.config
    def grailsApplication

    final int height
    final int width

    PhotoSize(int height, int width) {
        this.height = height
        this.width = width
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        height
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to store images sizes would be to have an `enum` like:

```
enum ImgSizeEnum {
    THUMBNAIL(100, 100),
    LARGE(200, 200)

    private final int height
    private final int width

    ImgSizeEnum(int height, int width) {
        this.height = height
        this.width = width
    }

    public int getHeight() { return height }
    public int getWidth() { return width }
}
```

Then in your Taglib you could have a param representing the `enum` as a `String` (in order to get its size):

```
ImgSizeEnum imgSizeEnum = ImgSizeEnum.valueOf("THUMBNAIL");
imgSizeEnum.getHeight()
imgSizeEnum.getWidth()
```

In this example I've hard-coded sizes in the enum but you can store those values in `Config.groovy` as well.

**Edit:**

To take the height / width from `Config.groovy` add each values in the file like that:

```
img.thumbnail.height=100
img.thumbnail.width=100
```

Or using this syntax:

```
img{
    thumbnail{
        height=100
        width=100
    }
}
```

Then inject `grailsApplication` service in the enum class:

```
def grailsApplication
```

And read properties from the config file to initialise each enum:

```
enum ImgSizeEnum {
    THUMBNAIL(grailsApplication.config.img.thumbnail.height, grailsApplication.config.img.thumbnail.width),
...
}
```

Comment: That is a nice solution.  Now how would I get the values from Config.groovy into the enum declaration: LARGE(myConfig.photo.height, myConfig.photo.width)?

Comment: I've added an example on how to take those values from the Config file.

Comment: Hmmm, I've been struggling for an hour getting an enum to load the grailsApp.  Error: Apparent variable 'grailsApplication' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'grailsApplication' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.  I'm editing my post to include the full class.

Comment: Never mind, I think it was a different problem.  It seems to be working now.